# Finding a user based on _id

Tags: meteor

I'm making a simple messaging system, where if you decide to contact user X, a relationship is created with both their _ids. However, I'm trying to also add user X's name and picture into that same collection (lets ignore client side join between user collection and relationship collection as a possibility). In my method which inserts the the ids into the relationship collection I'm trying to query for user X (the person I'm contacting) based on his/her _id

```
Meteor.methods({
    getConversationId: function(contactAttributes){
       ...
      receiver = Meteor.users.find({_id: contactAttributes.receiverId});
      console.log(receiver.profile);
}
}
```

I'm getting undefined on the server side and the received document is empty on the sever,
I ran the same query on Meteor Mongo as

```
db.users.find({_id: 'xyz'});
```

and got the right document with the profile values, I'm not really sure whats going on, I'm guessing meteor restricts access to user data, but even on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out, I was returning a cursor. 2 ways to solve this, either use:

```
receiver = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: 'xyz'});
console.log(receiver)
```

or

```
receiver = Meteor.users.find({_id: 'xyz'}).fetch();
console.log(receiver[0])
```